# [jboss 7]How to safely cleanup the 'domain/content' directory?

Tags: jboss

I am a newby on JBoss and I work on *JBoss 7.1.3.Final* configured in domain mode.

I work with several almost identical environments: On all of them the directory "domain/content" is about 1Gb of data max.

```
$ du -sh content/
919M    content/
```

But on one of our environment this same directory is much bigger without reason :

```
$ du -sh content/
12G     content/
```

I've read it could be because of old data which are kept, is there a way to identify what is creating this problem and safely clean this directory ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally what I saw with other people : there is no real true safe way of doing it BUT you can do it manually. Think about doing a saveguard of the "content" directory

The "content" directory contains the deployments of wars. So first check the file "domain.xml" to extract the list of your deployments on the JBoss.

You will see a list of deployments with a SHA1 code associated

```
<deployments>
    <deployment name="mywar1-2.0.1.war" runtime-name="mywar1.war">
        <content sha1="5576f0057841532f4cb4a0b73d20545580fc91"/>
    </deployment>
    <deployment name="mywar2-2.0.1.war" runtime-name="mywar2.war">
        <content sha1="f54487d295b16e017fdde108100f734c22abda428"/>
    </deployment>
    <deployment name="mywar3-2.0.1.war" runtime-name="mywar3.war">
        <content sha1="c64546efcb652dcf414a302ceeca708a764772b"/>
    </deployment>
```

The two first characters of the SHA1 code are importants

the directory domain/content/ will have such listing :

```
~/mydomain/content$ ls -l
total 20
...
drwxr-xr-x 3 user group 4096 Apr  1 10:53 55
drwxr-xr-x 3 user group 4096 Apr  1 10:52 61
drwxr-xr-x 3 user group 4096 Apr  1 10:52 85
drwxr-xr-x 3 user group 4096 Mar 14 15:09 c6
drwxr-xr-x 3 user group 4096 Aug 23  2017 f5
```

You can basically delete all the files which ARE NOT NAMED by the two first letters of an SHA1 code.
So in my case the directories **61** and **85** can be deleted.